# Wix component won't update when patched

Tags: wix, windows-installer, patch

I'm creating a patch that will update my MSI built in WiX. I have one component that only has a `sqlupdatescript` that handles all my database changes.

When I need to update my db I add another `sqlscript` in that component. The problem is that if I create a patch that ONLY has an added `sqlscript` in that component the patch won't do anything. If I make a change in a file (within the same feature) the `sqlscript` will also run.

Is this expected behavior in WiX?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Installer detects the changes by the changes in the resource marked as `KeyPath`. It can be file  or registry key, for instance. I suppose your component contains a single file, which automatically makes it a key path. Thus, when you change only a script, the file doesn't change, and Windows Installer   doesn't know that something was changed. Otherwise, it correctly detects the change and applies the patch.

Comment: In fact, my component contains no files at all. Only sqlscripts. Do you mean that marking it with "keyfile" would make wix see the change? Or do I have to add a fake file that I update every time I want to just run my scripts?

Comment: If it's not a key path item then yes, it won't be detected as changed, which is why best practice is to have every component have one resource, marked as key.  Changing a script that's not a key path won't be detected as something that's changed. It is unwise to alter key path relationships in a patch, so don't change it until you do a major upgrade.